# Can someone explain what this Java code does?

Tags: java

I study Java as a subject in college and I got this code in the sheet to get the output, I executed the code to get the result of (11).

```
int i;  
for (i=1; i<10; i+=2);
System.out.println(i);
```

But what does it really do?

Comment: Note the semicolon after the for.

Comment: One of the best arguments I know for always using the opening and closing braces, even if it's a loop body with one line.  IntelliJ would have caught this blooper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start at the beginning, declare a variable named `i` of type `int`.

```
int i;
```

Now we shall loop, initialize `i` to the value `1`, while `i` is less than `10` add `2` to `i` (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11). `11` is not less than `10` so stop looping.

```
for (i=1; i<10; i+=2);
```

Finally, print `i` (11).

```
System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone is being sneaky. Here's how it would lay out indented norrmally:

```
int i; 
for (i=1; i<10; i+=2)
    ; 
System.out.println(i);
```

`int i;` declares a variable named `i` of type `int`.

```
for (i=1; i<10; i+=2)
    ;
```

is a `for` loop that starts by setting `i` to `1`, and then loops while `i` is less than `10, adding 2 to`i` each time.  The semicolon after the for is a no-op, an empty statement.

Try this version and see what happens:

```
int i; 
for (i=1; i<10; i+=2)
    System.out.println(i); 
System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code could be written more clearly like this (I will include comments denoting what each section does):

```
//declare a number variable
int i;

//this is a for loop
//the first part sets i to 1 to begin with
//the last part adds 2 to i each time
//and the middle part tells it how many times to execute
//in this case until i is no longer less than 10
for (i = 1; i < 10; i+=2);

//this prints out the final value, which is 11
System.out.println(i);
```

So your code will start i at 1 and then loop
i = 3, i = 5, etc. until i is no longer less than 10 which happens when
i = 9, i = 11
Then the program stops and you print the final value of i